# Why isn't this C inline array optimized correctly?

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, clang

For some reason, when I try to create an inline array of ints, the compiler optimizes it to the wrong values.

Here's some code that demonstrates the issue:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct queue_t {
    uint32_t count;
    uint32_t *nums;
} queue_t;

uint32_t queue_num1;
uint32_t queue_num2;

void build_queue_nums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        queue_num1 = i;
        queue_num2 = i + 1;
    }
}

void print_queue(queue_t *info) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < info->count; i++) {
        printf("index[%d] = %x\n", i, info->nums[i]);
    }
}

void test_queue() {
    queue_t info;

    if (queue_num1 == queue_num2) {
        printf("the same\n");

        info.count = 0;
        info.nums = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("not the same\n");
        uint32_t indices[] = { queue_num1, queue_num2 };

        info.count = 2;
        info.nums = indices;
    }

    print_queue(&info);
}

int main() {
    build_queue_nums();
    test_queue();

    return 0;
}
```

The key line is

```c
uint32_t indices[] = { queue_num1, queue_num2 };
```

When I run this with default options, it works fine:

```
$ gcc -o queue-test queue_test.c && ./queue-test
not the same
index[0] = 4
index[1] = 5
```

But turn on optimization, and it breaks:

```
$ gcc -O -o queue-test queue_test.c && ./queue-test
not the same
index[0] = 0
index[1] = 0
```

Clang gives even stranger output:

```
$ clang -O1 -o queue-test queue_test.c && ./queue-test
not the same
index[0] = fa98b060
index[1] = 563a
```

Is this some undefined behavior, or a compiler bug?

Comment: `info.nums = indices;` This saves a pointer to an automatic array that ceases to exist when the block ends at the next line of code. Any use of `info.nums` after that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. What about an assignment like `info.nums = (uint32_t[]){queue_num1, queue_num2};`? It seems to work for me, but does it have the same potential undefined behavior?

Comment: That would be the same UB. Lifetime of [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) follows the enclosing scope, in this case the `else` block.

Comment: Probably what you want is to `malloc` the array, and then make sure to `free` when done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `info.nums` to point to a local object `indices` that goes out of scope before you actually use it in `print_queue(&info);`... The code has undefined behavior.

You should rewrite the code as:

```
void test_queue() {
    queue_t info;

    if (queue_num1 == queue_num2) {
        printf("the same\n");

        info.count = 0;
        info.nums = NULL;
        print_queue(&info);
    } else {
        printf("not the same\n");
        uint32_t indices[] = { queue_num1, queue_num2 };

        info.count = 2;
        info.nums = indices;
        print_queue(&info);
    }
}
```

or possibly:

```
void test_queue() {
    queue_t info;
    uint32_t indices[] = { queue_num1, queue_num2 };

    if (queue_num1 == queue_num2) {
        printf("the same\n");

        info.count = 0;
        info.nums = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("not the same\n");

        info.count = 2;
        info.nums = indices;
    }

    print_queue(&info);
}
```